# Сформировать квадратную матрицу c#

Tags: c#, матрицы

Сформировать квадратную матрицу размера nxn, n=37 по
заданному образцу. В полученной матрице найти сумму всех
элементов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть вот такой код, но он выдает все единицы. Помогите исправить, пожалуйста.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main() {
        int n = 37;
        int[,] matr = new int[n,n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) Console.Write("{0,4}", matr[0, i] = matr[n - 1, i] = matr[i, 0] = matr[i, n - 1] = 1);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
        matr[i, j] = (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == n - 1 || j == n - 1) ? 1 : 0;
```